# Recursively searching a directory, but NullPointerException for system directories

Tags: java, recursion

I am using this code to search for a specific file pattern recursively in a given directory:

```
if (file.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("Searching directory ... "
                + file.getAbsoluteFile());
        if (file.canRead()) {
            System.out.println("Can read...");
            if (file.listFiles() == null) {
                System.out.println("yes it is null");
            }
            for (File temp : file.listFiles()) { // Problemetic line
                if (temp.isDirectory()) {
                    search(temp);
                } else {
                    // code to find a file
                }
            }
}
```

Above code outputs me like this (also I get exception):

```
Searching directory ... C:\swsetup\SP46840\Lang\zh-TW
Can read...
Searching directory ... C:\System Volume Information
Can read...
yes it is null
```

Exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Demo.search(Demo.java:61)
at Demo.search(Demo.java:63)
```

In my code the line is pointing to : `(file.listFiles())`, because it is trying to get list of files from system directories like "System Volume Information". I assume because it's a system directory, so some problem maybe happening which I am not aware.

My question is:

- How to handle this scenario, so that even `NullPointerException` occurs my `foreach` loop continues?
- Or better how to avoid exception in first place (like by checking if it is a system directory etc)?

Can anyone please guide me in this? Note: This is happening in Windows XP (I have tested earlier in Windows 7 few months back but I assume issue was not occurring there)

Comment: maybe you have no permission to read file list?

Comment: @MustafaGenç, yes even I initially thought same. But I have permission for that directory.

Comment: @Ashalynd, Let me try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (file.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("Searching directory ... "
                + file.getAbsoluteFile());
        if (file.canRead()) {
            System.out.println("Can read...");
            if (file.listFiles() == null) {
                System.out.println("yes it is null");
            } else { /* add the else */
              for (File temp : file.listFiles()) { // Problemetic line
                  if (temp.isDirectory()) {
                      search(temp);
                  } else {
                      // code to find a file
                  }
              }
            }
}
```

Comment: Great it's working fine! I did such a small mistake. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (file.listFiles() == null) {
      System.out.println("yes it is null");
      continue;
}
```

When you find that the directory does not contain any files then just `continue` to the start of loop and check other directory.

So using this when your logic finds that any directory does not contain any files you would skip all the processing(foreach loop) after this check, and you will avoid the `NullPointerException` and successfully skip the present directory.

### A standard approach for testing of preconditions in a loop

```
foreach(.....){

 //check for preconditions
 continue; // if preconditions are not met

 //do processing

}
```

Comment: cause it's basically a GOTO... and it's never necessary, if-else can always work instead... and once your loop grows, it hurts readability... just don't use it

Comment: @iluxa IMHO it makes the intent of the code more readable than just nesting the code in defensive != null checks or placing nested if else blocks. continue is a great help, and you should not avoid it.

Comment: @iluxa `continue` is perfectly fine. Just because you find deeply nested if/else pleasant to read doesn't mean we do.

Comment: `continue` is fine in a case like this... But once your for-loops grow a bit into smth like `switch() { if() { for() { if() { for() {...` , and the inner for is 150-lines long, and it has 2 `continue` s and 3 `break` s, not to be confused with the `switch` 's `break` s... if-else kind of structure keeps it traceable at least

Comment: @iluxa then maybe your method is doing a bit too much. That's not the problem of continue, but problem of your method maybe.

Comment: I'm not talking about the code you write. I'm talking about the code you're forced to read & maintain. `continue` doesn't make it any easier.

Comment: @iluxa yes I hear you. But actually the problem if you see is not that continue is goto, but more that the code is already unreadable. A well written readable method can make uses of continue and it would look more cleaner.

Comment: My approach to this - gotta know the rules in order to break the rules. I'm actually teaching a class tomorrow about Guice; I'm going to go off with "NEVER EVER USE a, b, c, d, e, ..." - not because a, b, c, and d indeed don't work - I just don't want to see newbies go there. Let them get a good grasp of basics first.

Comment: @iluxa Don't wanna argument and its not just me who thinks this. Lets just leave it to everyone has their own approaches to things. Read this link http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/58237/are-break-and-continue-bad-programming-practices

Comment: Yup, seen that. Lets agree to disagree :)

Comment: @iluxa yep we both know what we are doing ;)

Answer (score 1):

from javaDoc:

> ```
>  An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and
>  directories in the directory denoted by this abstract
>  pathname.  The array will be empty if the directory is
>  empty.  Returns <code>null</code> if this abstract pathname
>  does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.
> ```

So it's good idea to check null and use approach from Narendra Pathai's anwser